# A neat way to implement Linear Congruential Generator for ids in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, userid

A bit of introduction: After pondering over what kind of unique ids which will be exposed in URLs and elsewhere to use I've chosen Linear Congruential Generators (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). 
Why not UUIDs or auto-increment?

- UUIDs are too long and harder to store in db (the recommended way is to convert them to VARBINARY(16)).
- Auto_increment exposes sequence of registrations and additions of new entities and gives an ability to predict next ids. For example, if a service gets popular, users can make multiple registrations to get hold of a nice id and then try to sell such an account, ids will give some kind of status: the earlier the registration the cooler. I prefer to avoid such things.

With LCG the sequence is randomized and I can choose parameters so that possible values will fit nicely into a data type for a particular purpose. For example, use INT UNSIGNED for userids and choose parameters to give a period of 2^32.

The problem is that to generate the next id I need to get the value of the last id:

```
nextId = (a * lastId + c) % m
```

1. As I understand I have to set the very first id myself? Is it important which number I choose?
2. What is a neat way of generating new ids? Perhaps create a table with a list of last generated ids for each table? Or add an auto_increment column to each table to keep track of last generated id? And how to avoid problems when there are lots of registrations in a short amount of time?

**Update1:**
I've found one approach which is multi-user safe using info from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

```
CREATE TABLE sequences (users INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, posts BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO sequences VALUES(123456,123456789);
```

And then to get a new ID:

```
UPDATE sequences SET users=LAST_INSERT_ID((a * users + c) % m);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this reliably in MySQL you're going to need to write a stored procedure, and use a one-row table with the latest ID in it.

Your stored procedure needs to lock the table, read the latest ID, generate the new ID, update it into the table, unlock the table, and return the new ID to the caller.

You could also keep a multi-row table with the list of IDs you have generated.  In that case your stored procedure needs to lock, read the *most recently generated* ID, generate a new one, insert it into the table, unlock, and return.  Obviously in this case you're going to need a reliable way to find the most recently generated ID.  Perhaps using an autoincrement column and an ID column would do the trick.

Another way to accomplish what you want is to write a stored procedure that generates a multi-digit random number (I'd go with at least 48 binary digits), then attempts to insert it as the primary key of a table. As long as the insert fails due to key collision, try another random number.  These long random numbers are even harder to predict than your LCG sequence.

You must test your stored procedure rigorously under a heavy multi-client load once you've developed it, before you put it into production. If you don't test adequately, you *will* be sorry. I know by experience this stuff is hard to get right.

The UUID does have the size disadvantage you mention. But it has a very strong advantage: it's been thoroughly tested.  You don't need to try to reinvent the wheel if you choose it. (In my experience reinventing wheels, I've come up with some flat tires.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've updated the question and encourage you to assess the solution I've found. I don't want to use UUID for userids because I don't want URLs like example.com/user/550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000 or example.com/user/140282366920938463463374607431768211456